# obj doesnt get variable

Tags: object, processing

I've got a processing program that is supposed to display 100 rings each one a bit bigger than the previous. when i run my program it shows 1 ring that is the biggest. i this case 100px from the middle.

here's my code:

```java
Car[] myCar = new Car[100];
void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  noFill();
  for (int i = 0; i != myCar.length; i=i+1) {
    myCar[i] = new Car(i);
  }
}
void draw(){
  for (int i = 0; i != myCar.length; i=i+1) {
    myCar[i].drive();
    myCar[i].display();
  }
}
class Car{
  int c;
  Car(int c_){
   c = c_;
  }
  void drive(){
    c = c + 2;
  }
  void display(){
    background(255);
    noFill();
    stroke(10);
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    ellipse(width/2,height/2,1+c,1+c);
  }
}
```

my question is: why is only the biggest ring displayed?

it could be that

```java
for (int i = 0; i != myCar.length; i=i+1) {
  myCar[i] = new Car(i);
}
```

somehow doesn't give the variable "i" to my constructor.
or that I'm just dumb. I don't know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to write values into console and then check if they are correct. If everything is fine then your display method is not right.

Answer (score 1):

You don"t see them because when you call `myCar[i].display()`, that function clears everything that is already on the screen and sets `background(255)` and then goes on to draw a ring. This keeps happening and you only see one ring that is growing bigger and bigger every frame.

Just remove `background(255)` from the `display()` function and make it the first line of `draw()` and you will have your desired results.

Not always but for most cases, `background()` is called in either `setup()` or `draw()` because what it does is fill each pixel of the canvas with a color, think about that.